# String.Split() returns empty value

Tags: c#, string, split

I need to read only specific portions of a complete string. The string would be in the form of:

"1 Some Currency Name = 0.4232 Other Currency Name"

So, the quickest method I could come up with was to split the string at the equal (=) operator thus adding two values to the array, like so:

```
string rawInput = "1 Some Currency Name = 0.4232 Other Currency Name";
string[] rawSplit = rawInput.Split('=');
string firstRate = rawSplit[0].ToString();
string secondRate = rawSplit[1].ToString();
```

I now need to get only the first part of the secondRate string ("0.4232"). So I would split that string again (bad coding):

```
string[] lastSplit = secondRate.Split(); //Split at whitespace characters
string firstValue = lastSplit[0].ToString(); //Should return "0.4232" but instead returns ""
```

When I run the application to test this function, it returns an empty string instead of the value "0.4232". Why is this happening? What am I missing here?

Complete Method:

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rawInput = "1 Some Currency Name = 0.4232 Other Currency Name";
    string[] rawSplit = rawInput.Split('=');
    string baseRate = rawSplit[0].ToString(); //1 Some Currency Name
    string conversionRate = rawSplit[1].ToString(); //0.4232 Other Currency Name

    rawSplit = GetSplit(conversionRate);
    XtraMessageBox.Show(rawSplit[0].ToString()); //Returns blank string here???
}

private string[] GetSplit(string inputString)
{
    return inputString.Split();
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions welcome and will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you split at `=` then the string will be ` 0.4232...` which means the first entry is empty when splitting by whitespace.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you calling `ToString()` on values which are already strings?

Answer (score 14):

The problem is, when you split your original string at `'='`, you're getting a result with an extra space at the beginning in the result, basically `rawSplit[1]` is equal to `" 0.4232 Other Currency Name"`.

You can use the overload of [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) that allows you to specify to remove empty entries, which will trim off any blank entries in the result.

```
string[] lastSplit = secondRate.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

On a side note, there is no need to use `ToString()` when the input is already a string:

```
string[] rawSplit = rawInput.Split('=');
// rawSplit is a string array, so rawSplit[0] is already a string...
string firstRate = rawSplit[0]; // .ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem can be solved as already been answered by Reed Copsey

```
new[] {' '}
```

However, I am showing some other ways of doing so

**By using Regular Expression**

```
var result = Regex.Match(secondRate, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value;
```

But suppose your input string is of type `"0.4232 Other Currency Name 0.45"` where you need to match both the decimal values. In that case you can go ahead with `Regex.Matches`

e.g.

```
string secondRate ="0.4232 Other Currency Name 0.45";
var result = Regex.Match(secondRate, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value;

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(secondRate, @"\d+(\.\d+)?");
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
               foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Value={1}", capture.Index, capture.Value);
               }
           }
```

**By Using Where extension methods**

Complete code

```
string rawInput = "1 Some Currency Name = 0.4232 Other Currency Name 0.45";
            string[] rawSplit = rawInput.Split('=');
            string firstRate = rawSplit[0].ToString();
            string secondRate = rawSplit[1].ToString();
            string[] lastSplit = secondRate.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            decimal num = 0;
            lastSplit
                .Where(d => decimal.TryParse(d, out num))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

**Output**

```
0.4232
0.45
```

Answer (score 0):

The below will return the string " 0.4232 Other Currency Name"

```
string conversionRate = rawSplit[1].ToString();
```

This has a space before it so when split again at:

```
return inputString.Split();
```

The 0 position in the array is that space, you either want position 1 or do a trim before that final split.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of string is `= 0.4232`, There is a whitespace between = and 0.4232. So when you split, the first entry is empty string. You can either check the second entry, but better way would be to `string.Trim()` before using `string.Split()`

Answer (score 0):

As stated before by other users, the problem is the white space. One simple solution would be adding trim() to conversionRate:

```
rawSplit = GetSplit(conversionRate.Trim());
```

That will allow to keep the rest of your code intact (even so, it would be advisable to take out the unnecessary use of ToString()).